# Backbone model.save() not appending ID to end of URL

Tags: api, backbone.js, put

I have an issue with a backbone PUT request returning 405 (Method not allowed).  This is happening because the model.save() in the code is not sending to the model url with the ID of the model on the end.

This is the PUT.

```
Remote Address:::1:670
Request URL:http://localhost:670/api/contacts
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Authorization:Bearer YLPwKSpBsBrFUemRHdjz....
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:417
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:670
Origin:http://localhost:660
Referer:http://localhost:660/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Request Payloadview source
{id:1, ContactOrganisation:Cow on a Mission, ContactPerson:Ben Drury, Phone:07980567574,…}
Address: "----"
ContactOrganisation: "----"
ContactPerson: "Ben"
CreatedBy: "----"
CreatedOn: "2014-03-03T16:40:50.037"
Description: "----"
Email: "---"
Organistion: "----"
Phone: "----"
Website: "http://www.cogiva.com"
id: 1
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:GET,POST,OPTIONS
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:72
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 17 Apr 2014 13:56:38 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
ConsoleSearchEmulationRendering
```

If I do the put through a REST console and add the id to the URL it works.  But direct from this code:

```
      this.model.set($(e.currentTarget).data("modelfield"), $(e.currentTarget).val());
      console.log("model",this.model);
      this.model.save({
          success: function(model, response){
            console.log("Yup!");
            $(self.el).find('.update_loader').removeClass("running");
            $(self.el).find('.update_loader').addClass("done");
          },
          error: function(){
            console.log("No!");
            $(self.el).find('.update_loader').removeClass("running");
            $(self.el).find('.update_loader').addClass("error");                
          }
      });
```

The model on the console just before the post, definitely had an ID.  Why would it not be forming the URL correctly?

Model Def:

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',

], function ($, _, Backbone){

    var ContactModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      url: "http://localhost:670/api/contacts"        
    });

    return ContactModel;

});
```

Comment: Looks like the `id` is put in the body as a property. This could be caused by many reasons. Have you overwrite `url` of the model's collection?

Comment: No. Not in the code. It's only set in the model definition.

Comment: Can you share the definition code?

Comment: Yup no problem. Added.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Setting `Model.url` just gives the model a constant URL.  If you want the model ID appended, then you need to specify `Model.urlRoot` instead.  This will generate URLs of the form "/api/contacts/id":

```
var ContactModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "http://localhost:670/api/contacts"        
});
```

Alternatively, if the model is stored in a collection, then you could set `Collection.url` to the same.  See the notes for [`Model.url`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url):

> Delegates to Collection#url to generate the URL, so make sure that you have it defined, or a urlRoot property, if all models of this class share a common root URL. A model with an id of 101, stored in a Backbone.Collection with a url of "/documents/7/notes", would have this URL: "/documents/7/notes/101"

Comment: I believe this is correct from what I have read, but this isn't working for me and I have no idea why

Comment: To people who want to remove the ID at the end, I used "url" instead of "urlRoot". So it works both ways, ofcourse. :)

Answer (score 3):

You overwrite the `url` property. That's why it's fixed - backbone calls this property/function to get the url. And the default `url` function implementation uses `urlRoot`. 
Change code to this should work:

```
var ContactModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "http://localhost:670/api/contacts"        
});
```

Check this: [model.url](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url)

If your url format is special (not `urlRoot/id`) you need to overwrite `url` with a function to provide custom implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You mask the default behavior of [`Model.url`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) by setting an explicit `url` attribute on your `ContactModel` definition. Use [`Model.urlRoot`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) instead:

```
var ContactModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "http://localhost:670/api/contacts"        
});
```